# Disable form without losing post data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, sinatra

If I do that

```
function disableSearchForm(){
    $("#myform :input").prop("disabled", true);
  }
$(document).on("click", "#ididid123", function(){
    disableSearchForm();
    $.ajax({
         //............
    });

    return false;
  });
```

then nothing comes in `params` due to call of `disableSearchForm();`. So can I "have my cake and eat it too"? I want to disable the form and still have ability to read post data from `params`.

Comment: Kinda strange that it would do that, but why not just change the order (send the ajax call, then disable fields)?

Comment: collect data, disable form, send ajax

Comment: Disable the submit button instead of the entire form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) the form before disabling the inputs:

```
$(document).on("click", "#ididid123", function(){
    var data = $('#myform').serialize();
    disableSearchForm();
    $.ajax({
      data: data
      //............
    });
    return false;
});
```